# Trouble with adding dropdown menu on responsive navigation

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I tried different things to add harmlessly sub menu, but I couldn't manage to do it. Here's the Pen:

`[1]: https://codepen.io/AlmostCrispyObject/pen/qZKKra`

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

HTML:

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="">За матурата</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="">Матурата в цифри</a></li>
        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="">Конспект</a></li>
        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="">ЧЗВ</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu {display:none}
li:hover > .submenu {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: thanks,but i need the sticky navigation to have also a dropdown